# Any way to test that a method fires on my object?

Tags: testing, phpunit

Using latest PHPUnit, I've been using mocks to solve a lot of my needs (such as mocking the GuzzleHttp\Client to test my api calling methods) but I've run into something I have yet to figure out how to test.

```
class Foo {
    public function alpha($payload): void
    {
        // If some things are found in payload then...
        $this->beta();
    }

    public function beta(): void
    {
        // do some stuff behind the scenes
    }
}
```

Given the above example, I'd like to test that when a particular type of payload is passed into Foo::alpha(), that Foo::beta() ends up getting fired. If beta() was a method on some other object, then I could mock the object and allow it to be passed in to the Foo instance and tell it to expect beta() to fire once, etc, but I'm unsure of how I can test this trigger is firing when it's no the same object.

Is this possible to do with PHPUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: You can use a partial mock

```
    public function test()
    {
        $foo = $this->createPartialMock(Foo::class, ['beta']);

        $foo->expects(self::once())
            ->method('beta');

        $foo->alpha(/* payload to trigger call to beta */);
    }
```

The longer answer is: You probably shouldn't use a partial mock. Most of the time it's an indicator that something's off with the design. If calling `beta` doesn't have any effect you can sense, why is it even necessary to verify that it has been called? I guess your code has some reason in it. Maybe your class has an implicit dependency or it has multiple responsibilities that should be split into separate classes. Without seeing actual code it's hard to tell, though.

Comment: What I was doing was providing a class with some placeholder methods that would be fired under certain conditions and where the intention was that the end user would extend this class for their implementation and override only the methods they wished to include functionality for said events (thus why the methods themselves weren't just abstracts...I wanted them to be able too fire and do nothing if the user ignored them).

In light of the issues of trying to test this, I changed it to a method more like what you describe. Now listeners are registered and fired instead (and can be mocked).